# How to use RTK query under useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I have a situation where I tried to fetch data when user login , and my structure is I have two redux slice one is userData other one is UserCartData  and

1. when user login ,if login success ,
2. then I will dispatch data into UserData ,
   3, then I write a useEffect to check if there's userData ,
3. I will then fetch UserCartData with UserData

But the thing is I can't get useGetxxxQuery work under useEffect,here's my code

```js
const Login = () => {
  const user = useAppSelector(state=> state.auth);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [login] = useLoginMutation();
  const [showPassword,setShowPassword] = useState<boolean>(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user!==null){ //fecth userCart data with userData
      const {data ,isLoading,isFetching }= useGetCartByIDQuery(user.user?._id!)
    }
  }, [dispatch])
  return (
    <Container>
      <Wrapper>
        <Title>SIGN IN</Title>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object({
            password: Yup.string()
              .min(8, 'Must be 8 characters or higher')
              .required(),
            email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email address').required(),
          })}
          onSubmit = {  async (values, actions) => {
                try{
                  const result = await login(values);
                  if("data" in result){
                    //console.log(result.data.data)
                    dispatch(setCredentials({user:result.data.data.findUser,token:result.data.data.cookie}))
                    
                  }else{
                    const err = (result.error as RequestError).data.message
                    if(err.includes("password")){
                      actions.setErrors({password:err})
                    }else if(err.includes("Facebook")){
                      actions.setErrors({email:err})
                    }
                  }
                }catch(err){
                  console.log(err)
                }             
          }}>
          //....unrelevant code
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a `useEffect` here, you can simply use `skipToken`:

```js
import {skipToken} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'

const {data, isLoading, isFetching } = useGetCartByIDQuery(user.user ? user.user._id : skipToken)
```

Answer (score -3):

**You can not use hooks inside other hooks. It is a rule!!!** 
 Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html 
 Instead of this you can change `useGetCartByIDQuery` hook and use only a function from there: ex: `const { startFetch } = useGetCartByIDQuery`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  startFetch('your arguments')
}, [])
```

Comment: I know , but I am wondering how to resolve the situation when using RTK query

Comment: @Kai021195, if `useGetCartByIDQuery` hook is not a custom hook, you can create instead your own custom hook using `useGetCartByIDQuery`, and there you can implement your logic. After that you can follow the example from my answer. Please let me know if you understand.

Comment: useGetCartByIDQuery is a hook from RTK query  https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries , I am not sure what you mean by "custom hook" ?

Comment: You can create your own hook where you will be able to use other hooks.